# Xpath union multiple queries

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

I am scrapping jobs from another website. The source website has different cases as user copy paste the data and structure changes.

Case 1:

```
<h3>Job Description</h3>
<div style="text-align: justify; line-height: 115%"><b>
Receptionist is assigned for ANAFAE-ALC based in Mazar-e-Sharif. This position is supervised by and reports to ALC Educational Program Manager and following are the main duties but are not limited to that.</div>
```

Case 2:

```
<h3>Job Description</h3>
<p>
Receptionist is assigned for ANAFAE-ALC based in Mazar-e-Sharif. This position is supervised by and reports to ALC Educational Program Manager and following are the main duties but are not limited to that.</p>
```

In this case  the p tags sometimes replace other html tags.

Case 3:

```
<h3>Job Description</h3>
Receptionist is assigned for ANAFAE-ALC based in Mazar-e-Sharif. This position is supervised by and reports to ALC Educational Program Manager and following are the main duties but are not limited to that.
```

I am using this string to get content. This now works for Case 3 but not for other two cases. How can I fix t to work for all three cases.

```
//text()[preceding::h3[text()="Job Description"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath expression selects the text nodes that are preceded by an `<h3>` with a text node equal to "Job Description". That only matches the third case, as the first two cases respectively have a `<div>` and a `<p>` following the `<h3>`.

You could try something like this:

```
//node()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::h3 = "Job Description"]]/string()
```

Some details:

`//node()` selects all element or text node descendants from the initial context.

`preceding-sibling::*[1]` selects the first immediately preceding element.

`[self::h3 = "Job Description"]` checks that the element is an `<h3>`, and that its string value is equal to "Job Description".

`/string()` returns the string value of the context node. For your example content, `/descendant-or-self::text()` could be used. It works by selecting the context node if it is a text node, and all descendant text nodes if it's an element. However, if the `<div>` or `<p>` are changed to have mixed content (i.e., child elements interspersed with text nodes), that expression will return a sequence of the descendant text nodes, while `/string()` will concatenate them together.

Comment: It doesn't return anything. This is the full string I have now. `//node()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::h3 = "Job Description"]]/descendant-or-self::text() and following-sibling::h3[text()="Job Requirements"]]`

Comment: What's the execution environment for the XPath expression? How are you running this?

Comment: This works: `//node()[preceding::h3[node()="Contact Information"]`